# Makefile Not Applying -g Consistently Despite Rule

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb, g++

I'm unable to debug my application in gdb because the symbol tables are not loaded and I'm working backwards through my program to determine what is causing this to occur. The first suggestion that is mentioned is to include the -g flag when compiling and I set that in the CFLAGS portion of my makefile but it appears that it isn't getting applied to my files.

Without writing a makefile that is hardcoded with my file names to ensure that it works, how would I modify the existing one to ensure the -g flag is applied to all compiled    files?

```
$ make

g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++    -c -o scanner.o scanner.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -o scanner main.o scanner.o
```

I found this makefile and plugged in my information

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable

OBJFILES = main.o scanner.o 
TARGET = scanner

all: $(TARGET)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c
    

$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES)
    

.PHONY: clean
    
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET) *~
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add the line:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g
```

Since your Makefile does not provide rules to build from C++, Make is using the default rules.  Those rules apply CXXFLAGS to the compile command, but not CFLAGS.  Do not overwrite the default rule; just add to CXXFLAGS.  I would recommend you delete the rule for `%.o: %.c`, since that is the default that Make will use and there's no benefit explicitly providing a duplicate.